# dynamic message selector in JMS

Tags: java, jms

Consider the scenario,
 I have publishers,they are publishing data of same type.

suppose

```
{ "dataType":"D1","data":{"name":"Jon","age":34} }
```

Initially I have a selector **name='Jon'** but after some time I want to add age also.
i.e. now a message selector is **name='Jon' AND age>34**

so, it is possible to add dynamic message selector in JMS?

Note : There is no limit on aading message selector on data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you'll need to recreate the consumer to adjust the selector. Depending on provider implementation this might be expensive.

Consider if having separate destinations might be a better idea. Also messaging systems are not databases so may not have the sophisticated indexes that a DB would.